# this is bound incorrectly if jquery function is called from a stored variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, this

I'm calling a jQuery function in two ways, one works the other doesn't because `this` is bound incorrectly.

`$('#my-div').fadeOut();`

works as expected, the value of `this` inside the `fadeOut` function is the jQuery object.

```
var fadeOutFn = $('#my-div').fadeOut;
fadeOutFn();
```

doesn't work since value of `this` is now `Window`

here is the jsfiddle with both examples.

http://jsfiddle.net/XCAdP/

**Edit:** Adding some clarifications on why I posted the question, I don't really want to know how to fix this. that's not the issue. I want to understand why it's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does not know the element it is applying `fadeOut` animation to and `this` context will be mostly the window and not the jquery object in this case. You can pass the context using `function.call`

Try this:

```
var fadeOutFn = $('#my-div').fadeOut;
fadeOutFn.call($('#my-div'));
```

Or just do this:

use function.bind to bind the context to the function reference, and invoke it.

```
var fadeOutFn = $().fadeOut.bind($('#my-div'));
fadeOutFn();
```

Read [function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

For non supported browsers you can add this in your js file for support as mentioned in the document:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== "function") {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
    }

    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1), 
        fToBind = this, 
        fNOP = function () {},
        fBound = function () {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                                 ? this
                                 : oThis,
                               aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

Comment: I think the whole point is to not have to repeat `#my-div` when calling it.

Comment: @Barmar how about the second one using bind. You don't repeat in that case.

Comment: The `bind` mehod doesn't work in a little older browsers, like IE8. Use the `jQuery.proxy` method instead.

Comment: @PSL: Why add another library, when jQuery is already included?

Comment: it is not library.. just native javascript ecmascript standard. But i dont know it jquery already includes it or not... :) but your solution is great as well. i always forget about $.proxy

Comment: I added some explanations to the question. I'm not looking for a workaround, I just want to understand why it's happening and how to explain it.

Comment: @Keivan as i have mentioned in my answer fadeout or any jquery methods mostly look for the jquery object rep of element as its context inside the function i.e It doesnt get attached when you do elem.fadeout. it just gives the func reference and when you invoke it it will the context from where it is invoked in this case it will be window and its internal imp will fail.

Comment: @Keivan and thats what bind, $.proxy, call etc does it just changes the context (from the calling context) to what is mentioned in those methods as the context. Best way yuo can look at is stepping in to the fadeOut method in a non minified jquery code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when you get a method as a function reference, you disconnect it from the object. A function only works as a method when you call it in the context of an object, which is usually done with the `.` operator, e.g. `obj.method()`.

If you call a function without the context of an object, it's called with the global scope as context, i.e. the `window` object. Example:

```
var obj = {
  name: "obj",
  method: function() { alert(this.name); }
};

obj.method(); // shows the name "obj"
var m = obj.method;
m(); // shows the name of window
m.call(obj); // shows the name "obj"

var obj2 = {
  name: "obj2"
};
m.call(obj2); // shows the name "obj2" (using the method from obj)
```

If you want to make it work as a method, you have to call it with the object as context:

```
var obj = $('#my-div');
var fadeOutFn = obj.fadeOut;
fadeOutFn.call(obj);
```

You can use the [`proxy` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to make a function that calls the function with the correct context:

```
var obj = $('#my-div');
var fadeOutFn = $.proxy(obj.fadeOut, obj);
fadeOutFn();
```

Comment: My +1 for $.proxy. i always forget about it. But i think we can avoid `obj.fadeOut`

Comment: I added some explanations to the question. I'm not looking for a workaround, I just want to understand why it's happening and how to explain it.

Comment: @Keivan: I added a more descriptive explanation for the reason.